# Evaluating $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma} e^{3z} dz$ along a line segment?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma} e^{3z}\,dz $$ along the line segment from $1$ to $i$.

Seems easy enough, but for some reason I am getting a slightly different answer than the one in the back of the book.

An antiderivative of $f$ is $F(z) = \dfrac 13e^{3z}$, so the integral should simply be $F(i)-F(1) = \dfrac 13 (e^{3i} - e^3)$. However, the answer in the back of the book is $\dfrac 13 (e^{3} - e^{3i})$. Is it really supposed to be $F(1)-F(i)?$

Comment: You are right, the book is wrong, assuming the path starts at $1$ and ends at $i$.

Comment: @MPW Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: :-) The world isn't a perfect place... which is why we have peer review :P